# row of bounded functions, defined on an interval [a,b], whose limit function is not bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm searching for a row of bounded functions, defined on an interval [a,b], whose limit function (pointwise) is not bounded .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an unbounded function, like $f(x)=1/x$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$.

Then "truncate" $f$, i.e. set $f_n (x)=f(x)$ for $x\in (1/n,1]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Nice :). Thank you very much!!